# How to handle if delimiter appears in data in spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How to handle if my delimiter is present in data when loading a file using spark RDD.

My data looks like below:

```
NAME|AGE|DEP
Suresh|32|BSC
"Sathish|Kannan"|30|BE
```

How to convert this column into 3 columns like below.

```
NAME     AGE     DEP
suresh     32      Bsc
Sathish|Kannan      30     BE
```

Please refer the how i tried to load the data.

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///test/Sample_dep_20.txt",2)
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = hdfs://Hive/Sample_dep_20.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:27


rdd.collect.foreach(println)

101|"Sathish|Kannan"|BSC
102|Suresh|DEP


scala> val rdd2=rdd.map(x=>x.split("\""))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:29

scala> val rdd3=rdd2.map(x=>
     | {
     | var strarr = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
     | for(v<-x)
     | {
     | if(v.startsWith("\"") && v.endsWith("\""))
     |   strarr +=v.replace("\"","")
     | else if(v.contains(","))
     |   strarr ++=v.split(",")
     | else
     |   strarr +=v
     | }
     | strarr
     | }
     | )
rdd3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:31

scala> rdd3.collect.foreach(println)
ArrayBuffer(101|, Sathish|Kannan, |BSC)
ArrayBuffer(102|Suresh|DEP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to explicitly define `"` as a quote character (it is by default for `csv` reader but  maybe not in your case?). So adding `.option("quote","\"")` to the options when reading your .csv file should work.

```
scala> val inputds = Seq("Suresh|32|BSC","\"Satish|Kannan\"|30|BE").toDS()
inputds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val outputdf = spark.read.option("header",false).option("delimiter","|").option("quote","\"").csv(inputds)
outputdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: string, _c1: string ... 1 more field]

scala> outputdf.show(false)
+-------------+---+---+
|_c0          |_c1|_c2|
+-------------+---+---+
|Suresh       |32 |BSC|
|Satish|Kannan|30 |BE |
+-------------+---+---+
```

Defining makes `DataFrameReader` ignore the delimiters found inside quoted strings, see Spark API doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame).

**EDIT**

If you want to play hard and still use plain RDDs, then try modifying your `split()` function like this:

```
val rdd2=rdd.map(x=>x.split("\\|(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"))
```

It uses positive look-ahead to ignore `|` delimiters found inside quotes, and saves you from doing string manipulations in your second `.map`.

Comment: Hi Mazaneicha, Whatever you said will work with spark dataframe. But I wanted to achieve in spark RDD itself.

Comment: In that case, could you update the question with code sample showing how are you _"loading a file using spark RDD"_?

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. Additionally I am looking for dynamic escape characters instead of quotes(for instance ~,^,etc)

Comment: Just replace `"`s in that regex with desired character.